# Traversal with State monad

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, state-monad

With following code I want to combine map with state and keep Expr as state, but it mandates me to keep things inverse, so `Expr` must be result, and `[[]]` must be state, or gives me compilation error. any means to make it work my way ?

```
import Control.Lens (Traversal', mapMOf)

data Elem = E1 | E2 | X1 | Y2
data Expr = StrConst T.Text | PathConst (Maybe (Expr)) [T.Text] | FilterConst [Expr]

traversalXExpr :: Traversal' Expr Expr
traversalXExpr f = \case
  PathConst ptype cond steps -> X.PathConst ptype <$> traverse f cond <*> pure steps
  FilterConst exs -> FilterConst <$> traverse f exs
  x -> pure x

findNodesS :: Elem -> Expr -> [[Elem]]
findNodesS el xexpr = evalState (mapMOf traversalXExpr (processNodeS el) xexpr) []

processNodeS :: Elem -> Expr -> State Expr [[Elem]] 
processNodeS x y = undefined
```

This doesn't compile:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Expr -> State Expr [[Elem]]’
with ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT [a0] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Expr’
```

But compiles nicely with `processNodeS :: ... State [[Elem]] Expr`

Comment: What are you expecting `mapMOf` to do with the `[[Elem]]`s that get returned from `processNodeS`? *Normally* `mapMOf` replaces each of the elements visited during the traversal with the value returned from the callback function (`processNodeS`). But that can't work here, since you have to replace an `Expr` with an `Expr`, not replace an `Expr` with a `[[Elem]]`.

Comment: I want to traverse my `Expr` ADT as tree, I tried to do it with `Traversable`, but it requires ADT to have param (like `Expr a`) but I don't need it here

Comment: I don't think that comment actually addresses the question I asked.

Comment: I rely on this feature: https://cloudnative.ly/haskell-mapping-with-state-7a07e3c2cbf9. So I want to do foldmap or just map (not sure yet) with posssibility to access some state inside map function.